# FreeASPUpload ASP Clássico parou de funcionar

Tags: html, upload, asp

Na empresa em que estou trabalhando todos os sistemas foram construídos em ASP Clássico, e utilizamos o FreeASPUpload para baixar arquivos enviados através de form, porem hoje pela manhã esta classe parou de funcionar do nada. Alguém já passou por isso?

O código que uso para pegar as variáveis do form é este:

```
Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload  
uploadsDirVar = server.mappath ("upload\"&id_grupo_segmento)
SaveFiles = ""
Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)
ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys

id_pessoa = Upload.Form("id_pessoa")
id_pesquisa = Upload.Form("id_pesquisa")
id_grupo_segmento = Upload.Form("id_grupo_segmento")
id_status_contato = Upload.Form("id_status_contato")
id_status_pesquisa = Upload.Form("id_status_pesquisa")
```

o form utiliza o `ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Retorna alguma mensagem de erro, notificação, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Verifique se os servidores com as aplicações em ASP clássico receberam o update [KB3104002](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50312).

Ele atualizou os arquivos `VBScript.dll` e `JSCript.dll`, que intepretam os scripts.

Em tempo: Este tipo de ocorrência acontecerá mais e mais frequentemente, já que a Microsoft não oferece mais suporte à tecnologia. Sugiro a atualização para um framework mais moderno.

Comment: Obrigada lbotinelly, salvou o meu dia haha
Vou falar com a gerência e propor a atualização